# Cordova plugin.xml add "Header Search Paths" entry

Tags: xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I would like a new entry to be added under "Header Search Paths" once my Cordova plugin is added to an Xcode project.

How can I config it in my Cordova plugin.xml file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to do this on a project-wide basis.

However, there is a way to add to the search path for each of your source files, which accomplishes the same thing.  The [`source-file`](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification_source_file_element) element in plugin.xml supports a `compiler-flags` attribute.  To this attribute, you may add any flags that the compiler (in this case the `clang` command) supports.  The compiler flag to add to the header search path is `-I<path>`.  Note that if you include a space (eg `-I <path>`), Cordova will produce a misformatted `.xcodeproj` folder, and you will not be able to open the project in Xcode, nor build the Cordova project from the command line.  Note also that `<path>` in this case is relative to your `.xcodeproj` folder that Cordova generates.

So, for example, if you have these files in your plugin folder (let's call it ~/com.MyPlugin/):

```
myAngleHeader.h
mySource.m
mySource.h
```

where `mySource.h` contains the line `#include <myAngleHeader.h>`
and `mySource.m` contains the line `#include "mySource.h"`

You would then want to put into your plugin.xml (~/com.MyPlugin/plugin.xml):

```
<source-file src="myAngleHeader.h" />
<source-file src="mySource.h" />
<source-file src="mySource.m" compiler-flags="-ImyApp/Plugins/com.MyPlugin/" />
```

where "myApp" is the name of your Cordova project.  Note again that there must be no space after the `-I` flag.

This method unfortunately requires that the developer control both the plugin and the Cordova project.  It won't be very useful if you want to publish a plugin for all to use.  There is probably a better way to do this; I'd love to hear other solutions.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is just what I have been searching so long for, thanks. I just wanted to ask if it is possible to add more than one complier flag?
As I also need to add the compiler flag '-fno-objc-arc' to the same files.

Comment: I bet you could, but I haven't tried it myself.  Try putting the full list of compiler flags into that element - eg compiler-flags="-I/folder/ -fno-obj-arc" or something like that.  It might produce issues due to the space though.

Comment: @JohnWalthour Hey I figured out a way, gave an answer below.  Not sure if the @ replies work in posts.  I'll share my plugin with you when it is complete, it's really close.

Comment: @AlonAmir Here is my cordova plugin that uses hooks to modify header search paths on plugin install/uninstall - https://github.com/rossmartin/cordova-plugin-instagram-assets-picker

Answer (score 2):

@JohnWalthour

I needed to do this for a cordova plugin I am creating and with the ["after plugin install"](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html) hook it is possible.  I realized I could run a node.js script after install and modify the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` in `${project}/platforms/ios/cordova/build.xcconfig`.

It required getting dirty but it works great.  One crucial part of this working is that the Bundle name is assigned to `${PRODUCT_NAME}` in the info.plist so you can use `${PRODUCT_NAME}` in your `build.xcconfig` and it will interpolate with your project/app name.  Cordova already has the `${PRODUCT_NAME}` variable set for you.

Here is the relevant code -

plugin.xml (shortened for brevity and the important stuff)

```
<platform name="ios">
  .....
  <hook type="after_plugin_install" src="hooks/AfterPluginInstall.js" />
  <hook type="before_plugin_uninstall" src="hooks/BeforePluginUninstall.js" />
  .....
</platform>
```

AfterPluginInstall.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

let cwd = process.cwd();
let fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');

console.log('InstagramAssetsPicker AfterPluginInstall.js, attempting to modify build.xcconfig');

let xcConfigBuildFilePath = path.join(cwd, 'platforms', 'ios', 'cordova', 'build.xcconfig');
console.log('xcConfigBuildFilePath: ', xcConfigBuildFilePath);
let lines = fs.readFileSync(xcConfigBuildFilePath, 'utf8').split('\n');

let headerSearchPathLineNumber;
lines.forEach((l, i) => {
  if (l.indexOf('HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS') > -1) {
    headerSearchPathLineNumber = i;
  }
});

if (lines[headerSearchPathLineNumber].indexOf('InstagramAssetsPicker') > -1) {
  console.log('build.xcconfig already setup for InstagramAssetsPicker');
  return;
}

lines[headerSearchPathLineNumber] += ' "$(SRCROOT)/$(PRODUCT_NAME)/cordova-plugin-InstagramAssetsPicker/GPUImageHeaders"';

let newConfig = lines.join('\n');

fs.writeFile(xcConfigBuildFilePath, newConfig, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error updating build.xcconfig, err: ', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('successfully updated HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS in build.xcconfig');
});
```

BeforePluginUninstall.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

let cwd = process.cwd();
let fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');

console.log('InstagramAssetsPicker BeforePluginInstall.js, attempting to modify build.xcconfig');

let xcConfigBuildFilePath = path.join(cwd, 'platforms', 'ios', 'cordova', 'build.xcconfig');
console.log('xcConfigBuildFilePath: ', xcConfigBuildFilePath);
let lines = fs.readFileSync(xcConfigBuildFilePath, 'utf8').split('\n');

let headerSearchPathLineNumber;
lines.forEach((l, i) => {
  if (l.indexOf('HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS') > -1) {
    headerSearchPathLineNumber = i;
  }
});

if (lines[headerSearchPathLineNumber].indexOf('InstagramAssetsPicker') === -1) {
  console.log('build.xcconfig does not have header path for InstagramAssetsPicker.');
  return;
}

let line = lines[headerSearchPathLineNumber];
lines[headerSearchPathLineNumber] = line.replace(/\ "\$\(SRCROOT\)\/\$\(PRODUCT_NAME\)\/cordova-plugin-InstagramAssetsPicker\/GPUImageHeaders\"/i, '');

let newConfig = lines.join('\n');

fs.writeFile(xcConfigBuildFilePath, newConfig, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error updating build.xcconfig, err: ', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('successfully updated HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS in build.xcconfig');
});
```

Comment: Awesome!  That does sound like a solution that would make your plugin a lot more portable.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to update my header search paths via the config as it was always a manual task setting it on build day. I have since added this plugin:

[Cordova-Custom-Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-custom-config)

I was then able to add these to my config and didn't have to worry about it again.

```
<platform name="ios">
   <!-- Set orientation on iPhone -->
   <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations">
     <array>
       <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
       <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
     </array>
   </config-file>
   <!-- Set orientation on iPad -->
   <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad">
     <array>
       <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
       <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
     </array>
   </config-file>
   <!-- Set Header Search Paths-->
   <preference name="ios-XCBuildConfiguration-HEADER\_SEARCH\_PATHS" value="'$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include' '$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include' '$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)'" buildType="release" xcconfigEnforce="true" />
```